# Session Cookie (Authentication Related) Does Not Contain The "HTTPOnly" Attribute

Tags: asp.net, azure, backend

Can someone help me in resolving Qualy's issue?

After Qualys scan, there is an issue that says to add the HTTP Only flag. I have set the HTTP Only flag in `web.config` of Asp.Net Application but it doesn't resolve. We are using Azure Active Directory (single Sign-On) authentication.

Don't know where I can set the flag to true. Moreover, in some blogs, they mentioned modifying NuGet packages.
I have attached the screenshot. please refer to it. Thanks in advance.
Flags are: `wlidperf`, `ESTSAUTHLIGHT`, `brcap`, `ch`, `clrc`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the settings related to HTTPS Only option under the following root inside your Azure Dashboard:

Settings - Custom Domains - HTTPS Only

However, you have to checkup with your security options and configurations, because this can engender security related problems later down the road.

[image: Azure Dashboad]